# WrapText for WideString in Delphi

Tags: delphi, localization, internationalization, delphi-2007

Delphi has a [`WrapText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.WrapText) function:

```
function WrapText(const Line, BreakStr: string; const BreakChars: TSysCharSet; MaxCol: Integer): string;
function WrapText(const Line: string; MaxCol: Integer): string;
```

Now i need a version that handles WideStrings:

```
function WrapTextW(const Line: WideString; MaxCol: Integer): WideString;
```

Is any such function written somewhere already?

> WARNING: Not every wide string character is 2-bytes
>
> Which is why i'm afraid to write it

**Update**: Example of a character that takes more than 2-bytes to represent:

> Capital Latin W with ring and cedilla
>
> - Bytes: 57 00 66 03 27 03
> - Rendered in Chrome 17: [image]
> - Rendered in Internet Explorer 9: [image]
> - Rendered in Notepad using Segoe UI: [image]
> - Rendered in Notepad using Consolas: [image]
> - Rendered in your browser in sans-serif font: W̧̊
> - Rendered in your browser in `monospaced` font: `W̧̊`

Comment: This will lead probably to copy the source from the Delphi 2009 up as the answer. +1 anyway

Comment: @TLama: That's why i tagged it as the last version of Delphi that didn't have better widestring support (to keep David off my back!)

Comment: Tnt component suit has `WideWrapText` in `TntSysUtils.pas`

Comment: @IanBoyd Yeah, no doubt this is really D5 but the D2007 solution will be the same!!  ;-)

Comment: *I have a dream* that one day I will wake up and my D5 monster application will transform itself magically to XE2... :/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Quiet you!  Pretend, for the purposes of this question, that i'm in the "modern" age. :)

Comment: Oi vey, dude, if you're dealing with Unicode XML data and WideString types every day (as your questions suggest) you really need to ditch your ancient delphi version!

Comment: @WarrenP Got a couple dozen thousand dollars so we can upgrade?

Comment: BTW, I just noticed your "WARNING: Not every wide string character is 2-bytes" - What makes you think that? this is false.

Comment: @kobik Look at the charater **W̧̧̧̧ͦ** (Capital Latin W with ring and cedilla). It's one "*character*". But in UTF-16 would be six bytes:  `57 00 66 03 27 03` (or `U+0057 U+0366 U+0327`) If you were to blindly flip each UTF-16 code point: from `0057 0366 0327` to `0327 0366 0057` you would end up with invalid nonsense.

Comment: Interesting... I can see this "char" correctly only in FireFox. IE and Google Chrome shows `W` and some unknown gibberish. if I copy it to Notepad and save as Unicode I get 8 bytes (2 for Unicode header). so I guess `WideString` will hold 6 bytes for it (3 `WideChar`s). but this fact interesting as it is, dose not make a difference that `WideChar` is 2 bytes. I wonder how can you show this character in notepad for example...

Comment: @kobik Oh a `WideChar` is definitely two bytes, but not all *characters* fit in a single 2-byte `WideChar`. That's why the question has the warning. Chrome display's the character properly; Internet Explorer displays the cedilia correctly, but the ring is too far to the right)

Comment: so W + cedilla + ring represent a glyph. not a character.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by kobik, [TNT UnicodeControls](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index) has a unit `TntSysUtils` which includes following function :

```
function WideWrapText(const Line, BreakStr: WideString; const BreakChars: TSysCharSet;
  MaxCol: Integer): WideString; overload;
function WideWrapText(const Line: WideString; MaxCol: Integer): WideString; overload;
```

Alternate download site is [here](http://www.axolot.com/TNT/).