# How big is an nvarchar(max) as far as ADO is concerned?

Tags: delphi, ado, parameterized-query

i am trying to use [a parameterized query against ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> INSERT INTO Foo (Name, Value) VALUES(@name, @value)

In SQL Server the `Name` column is a `varchar` type. The `Value` column is an `nvarchar(max)`.

What *size* do i pass when creating a parameter when i don't know, or want to specify, the size?

```
procedure SaveTheThing(Connection: TADOConnection);
var
   sql: WideString;
   cmd: _Command;
begin
   sql := 'INSERT INTO Foo (Name, Value) VALUES(@name, @value)';

   cmd := CoCommand.Create;
   cmd.Set_ActiveConnection(Connection.ConnectionObject);
   cmd.Set_CommandType(adCmdText);
   cmd.Set_CommandText(sql);

   //and now add the parameters
   cmd.Parameters.Append(
         cmd.CreateParameter('@name', adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, filename)
   );
   cmd.Parameters.Append(
         cmd.CreateParameter('@value', adVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, GetXmlToWideString)
   );

   cmd.Execute({out}recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adCmdSomeThatDoesntCauseAnExcetpion or adExecuteNoRecords);
end;
```

The simple alternative was going to be:

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO Foo (Name, Value)'#13#10+
       'VALUES (+QuotedStr(filename)+', '+QuotedStrW(GetXmlToWideString)+')';
```

and be done already. But i thought i'd burn a few days trying to make parameterized queries a viable solution, and [avoid having to write a `QuotedStrW`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703491/wraptext-for-widestring-in-delphi).

Comment: You can store up to 2 GB in a `nvarchar(max)` column - so that would be the number you need to use

Comment: What issues do you have when you uses the -1 size? any error message?  ask because i use -1 wihout problems in nvarchar columns.

Comment: @RRUZ i'll tell you how it works [once i can get it working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725222/must-declare-the-variable-myvariable-error-with-ado-parameterized-query).

Comment: @RRUZ `-1` *seems* to not cause an error. Put that in the form of an answer and you'll win an accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-1` value in the size of a ADO parameter without problems.

Try this sample code , which  insert a 2MB string in the `Value` column

```
var
   sql: WideString;
   cmd: _Command;
   recordsAffected : OleVariant;
begin
   sql := 'INSERT INTO Foo (Name, Value) VALUES(?, ?)';
   cmd := CoCommand.Create;
   cmd.Set_ActiveConnection(Connection.ConnectionObject);
   cmd.Set_CommandType(adCmdText);
   cmd.Set_CommandText(sql);

   //and now add the parameters
   cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('@name', adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, 'AfileName'));
   cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('@value', adVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, StringOfChar('#', 2*1024*1024)));
   cmd.Execute({out}recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adExecuteNoRecords);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my answer on your other post:

> ["Must declare the variable @myvariable" error with ADO parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725222/must-declare-the-variable-myvariable-error-with-ado-parameterized-query)

to use parameters and parameter by name. Try to avoid using `_Command`, but use `TADOCommand` because it is more friendly (and simpler to code too). You can assign parameter to a value by using:

```
Parameters.ParamByName('xxxx').value := someValue.
```

Of course `someValue` data type must correspond to your SQL server column data type definition.

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi's [`TADOCommand` object doesn't support unicode strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740696/how-to-parameterize-widestrings-using-tadocommand-parameterized-query). Which was the only reason i have to use parameters.