# "Must declare the variable @myvariable" error with ADO parameterized query

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, parameterized-query

i am trying to use parameterized queries with ADO. Executing the `Command` object throws the error:

> Must declare the variable '@filename'

i declare the parameter `@filename` using `CreateParameter/Append`:

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO Sqm(Filename, data) VALUES(@filename, @data)';

command := CoCommand.Create;
command.Set_ActiveConnection(Connection.ConnectionObject);
command.Set_CommandText(sql);
command.Set_CommandType(adCmdText);
command.Parameters.Append(Command.CreateParameter('@filename', adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, Filename));
command.Parameters.Append(Command.CreateParameter('@data', adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, xml);

command.Execute({out}recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `:` instead of `@` before the params in the query. And remove the @ from where you add the parameters.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: *Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ':'* You'd be surprised, i certainly was, that nobody has ever posted an example of ADO parameterized queries. (plenty to be found with ADO.NET)

Comment: Looks like you are using the ado interfaces directly instead of tadocommand. Try with a `?` in the query where you put the variable name `values (?, ?)`. I'm a couple of hours away from a computer so I can't verify that it will work yet.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You're right. ADO doesn't support named parameters; that was my (third) problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far i know ADO doesn't supports named parameters in SQL sentences (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE), so you must use the `?` char to indicate the parameter

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO Sqm(Filename, data) VALUES(?, ?)';
```

and then assign the parameters values in the same order as are used in the sql sentence.

ADO 2.6 Introduces the [`NamedParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property, but it seems which only works with stored procedures.

Comment: Well that certainly explains why named parameters aren't working in ADO. *oi vay Microsoft*

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
uses ADODB, DB;
...
...
... and then in some event handler (e.g. button click),
var 
  aCommand :TADOCommand;
begin
  aCommand := TADOCommand.create(self);
  aCommand.ConnectionString := 'build the connection string or use TADOConnection and assign to Connection property instead of ConnectionString property';
  aCommand.commandText := 'INSERT INTO Sqm(Filename, data) VALUES(:filename, :data);';
  aCommand.parameters.paramByName('filename').value := 'test';
  aCommand.parameters.paramByName('data').value := 'some data';
  aCommand.execute;
  aCommand.free;
end;
```

I have been using parameter by names this way for TADOCommand and TADOQuery with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameters.AddWithValue as shown below

```
  connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password=RainbowTrout;";
  InsertQry = "Insert into Sections(Name, PartNumber, VersionNumber, Channel, Address, Status, IPAddr) "
        + "values(@SectionName, @PartNumber, @VersionNumber, @Channel, @Address, @Status, @IPAddr)";


  NewCfgConnection.ConnectionString = string.Format(connectionString, ConfigFN);
  NewCfgCommand.Connection = NewCfgConnection;
  NewCfgCommand.CommandText = InsertQry;
  NewCfgConnection.Open();

  // Clear parameter values from last record
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.Clear();

  // Insert record into sections table - set parameters
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionName", sSectionName);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", sPartNumber);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VersionNumber", sVersionNumber);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Channel", iChannel);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", iAddress);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", iStatus);
  NewCfgCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAddr", iIP);

  NewCfgCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```