# Excel VBA MySql parameterised update 'invalid parameter type'

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

I am creating an interface where users can use excel to seamlessly alter an SQL database. I can retrieve data fine however when updating records I get an 'invalid parameter type'.

It works fine with just concatenating values into the query, however to prevent SQL injections I require a parameterised query. I have tried substituting in the ADO datatype with the value however this has not changed anything. I have tried unnamed parameters which just always submits a value of 16 to the database instead of the desired string value

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ID = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
        Dim locValue As String
        locValue = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value

        Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
        Set Cm = New ADODB.Command

        Cm.NamedParameters = True
        Cm.CommandText = "UPDATE issues SET " _
        & "location = @location " _
        & "WHERE id = " & ID

        Dim locationParameter As ADODB.Parameter

        Set locationParameter = Cm.CreateParameter("@location", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
        Cm.Parameters.Append locationParameter
        locationParameter.Value = locValue

        SqlConnection(Cm)
End Sub
```

(I am aware that ID is not yet parameterized, the issue is with the location)

```vb
Public Function SqlConnection(Cm As ADODB.Command) As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String

    Server_Name = "127.0.0.1" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "issues_and_outages" ' Enter your  database name here
    User_ID = "root" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "password" ' Enter your password here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    Cm.CommandType = adCmdText
    Cm.ActiveConnection = Cn

    Set SqlConnection = Cm.Execute

End Function
```

The server is MySQL with an issues_and_outages table, having columns with:

- id (integer, unsigned, key, auto_increment)
- location (varchar(255), nullable)

When updating a cell, which should update the location column, an error of

"Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)': 
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.16] Invalid parameter type"

is given, with an error on the Cm.Execute line. However the database has a column of type varchar of size 255, which should be an adVarChar so I do not expect an error.

Comment: But, `TINYTEXT` is *not* a `VARCHAR`, as a `TEXT` data type it's closer to being a *blob of bytes*, which probably explains the `16` you were getting instead of the supplied string - so the ordinal parameters worked better than the named ones. Consider avoiding the more exotic data types and sticking to `VARCHAR`. If the reason for `TINYTEXT` is a performance concern, see "[TINYTEXT is probably never a good idea"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114860/48511).

Comment: Agreed with using `VARCHAR` if it's a small text; `TEXT` is likely inappropriate. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html). I bet that the `16` is the length prefix of the string.

Comment: I have updated the mysql table so location is now a varchar of length 255, however I'm still getting the same error. Interestingly it now appears to work with Cm.NamedParameters set to false and the parameters as ? in the query

Comment: So use ordinal parameters, and problem solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regularly discussed and concluded with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725607/1422451), the ADO API for most providers/drivers does not support named parameters for non-stored procedure SQL statement. Instead use the qmark, positional parameter style.

```vb
Set Cm = New ADODB.Command

With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = Cn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "UPDATE issues SET location = ? WHERE id = ?"

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("loc_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, locValue)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("id_param", adInteger, adParamInput,, ID)

    .Execute
End With
```