# How to parameterize widestrings using TADOCommand parameterized query?

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-5, parameterized-query

i am trying to use a parameterized query with Delphi TADOCommand:

```
var 
   s: WideString;
   cmd: TADOCommand;  
   recordsAffected: OleVariant;
begin
   cmd := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
   cmd.Connection := Connection;
   cmd.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO Sqm(Filename) VALUES(:filename)';

   s := AFilename;
   cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('filename').Value := s;
   cmd.Execute();
```

The resulting data in the database is complete mangled:

> C?:\U?s?er?s?\i??n?.A?V`A?T?O?P?I?A?\A?p?p?D??t??\L?o???l?\A?v?at??r? S?o?f?t?w?är¨? C?r??t?i??n?s?\S?o°f?t?w?r?? Q?u??li?t?y? M??t?r?i?cs?\C??S?-s?q?m?00.x?m?l

---

i **can** use a native parameterized ADO `Command` object. It saves the data correctly:

> C̬:\Ȗŝḙr͇s̶\i̜ẵn̥.ÀV̹AͧT̶O̠P̩I̿Ȁ\A͜p̥p̔D͑ẫt̒ā\L̫o͋ɕălͭ\A̼v̼ẵt͈ấr̄ S̫o̖f͎t̻w̵ạr͂ẽ C̾r̮ḛẵt͘iͩo̳n̬s̨\S̪ōf̒t͘w̚âr̿ɇ Qͬüẳlͮi̫tͥy̽ M͘ȇt̨r̟i̻çš\C͍MͥS̚-s̞q̕m͜00.xͤm̧l̝

but it's [very fragile and not suitable for production use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726212/using-wrong-type-with-parameterized-query-causes-error).

How can i use unicode/WideStrings with `TADOCommand` in Delphi?

**Bonus Chatter**

In SQL Server Profiler you can see the SQL being executed:

> exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Sqm(Filename) VALUES(@P1)', N'@P1 char(300),@P2 text', 'C?:\Us?er?s?\i?än?.A?V?A?T?O?P?I?À\A?p?p?D?ât?a\L?o?çal¯\A?v?at??r? So?f?t?w?ar?? C?r??á?i?o?n?s?\So¸f"t?w?ar?? Q?u??l?i?ty? M??t?r?i¸?s`\C?M°S?-s?q?m?00.?m¨´l¯                                                                                                                                            '

Which points out the problem - it's building the `WideString` parameter as a `char(300)` value. Make it not broke.

The last i see of my WideString before it goes down the parameter hole is:

```
ParameterObject.Value := NewValue;
```

where

- `NewValue` is a variant of type `VT_BSTR` (aka `varOleStr`) with the proper value
- `ParameterObject` is a native ADO `_Parameter` object, with a [`.Type` of 129 (`adChar`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Even trying to force the parameter type:

```
cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('filename').DataType := ftWideString;
cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('filename').Value := s;
```

doesn't help.

> **Note:** This question is part of a series on how to paramaterize `INSERT INTO foo (value) VALUES (%s)`
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726212/using-wrong-type-with-parameterized-query-causes-error
> - [How big is an nvarchar(max) as far as ADO is concerned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723757/how-big-is-an-nvarcharmax-as-far-as-ado-is-concerned)
> - [How to parameterize widestrings using TADOCommand parameterized query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740696/how-to-parameterize-widestrings-using-tadocommand-parameterized-query)
> - ["Must declare the variable @myvariable" error with ADO parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725222/must-declare-the-variable-myvariable-error-with-ado-parameterized-query)

Comment: @RRUZ Removed the extraneous `recordsAffected` parameter from the original question

Comment: I don't supposed you tried UTF-8, have you?

Comment: Uch Delphi5, please move on and use a unicode capable IDE/Compiler

Comment: @whosrdaddy Got $20,000 i can borrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it cannot be done in Delphi (5).

It might be fixed in newer versions of Delphi; but without anyone to test it we won't know.

**Q.**: How to parameterize widestrings using TADOCommand parameterized query?
**A.**: You can't. Sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('filename').Value := WideStringToUCS4String(s);
```

By the way, s is declared as widestring. is it necessary to have s as a widestring? How about just

```
var
  s : String;
```

in System.pas, UCS4String (UCS-4 byte or UTF-32 bits) is declared as:

```
...
...
UCS4Char = type LongWord;
...
UCS4String = array of UCS4Char;
...
function WideStringToUCS4String(const S: WideString): UCS4String;
...
function UCS4StringToWidestring(const S: UCS4String): WideString;
```

What data type you stored the filename column as ? Can sql server 2000 handle UTF-32 string?

Comment: `string` is an alias of `AnsiString`, which cannot hold unicode data. Nor do i have a [`WideStringToUCS4String`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_WideStringToUCS4String.html) function in my version of Delphi.

Comment: When storing a `UCS4String` into a variant what `VarType` does Delphi convert it to. COM, and ADO, have no [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) support, and variants cannot hold them.

Comment: Hi Ian, I'm using Delphi 7, and I can found UCS-4 string or UTF-32 (UCS4String in Delphi) and the functions WideStringToUCS4String and UCS4StringToWidestring in System.pas.